# Why do I get total count while using a group by clause?

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I am trying to count employees (from employees table) per division (departments table)
My approach was to

```
SELECT d.division, COUNT (first_name) 
FROM departments d, employees
GROUP BY d.division
```

I receive a total count of all (1000) employees multiplied by a number of identical divisions (with different departments), e.g. if 'Hardware' division has 'Automotive' and 'Tools' departments, I get a count of 2000.

Counting it within one table works fine (departments are both inside the 'employees' and 'departments' tables)

```
SELECT department, COUNT (first_name) 
FROM employees
GROUP BY department
```

{I have just started and there's not many ways to get feedback while studying by yourself}

Comment: Hi Yana, searching for Advice in Stackoverflow is, let me call it the hard way :). For SQL Questions you shold alwas provide a full Example with some demodata. you can use sqlfiddle.com for that. After that you should describe exactly what you expect to see after you Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query specifies

```
FROM departments, employees
```

but is missing a `WHERE` clause, so there’s nothing to restrict only employees in the specific division being counted for each division, instead including *every* employee in *every* division (see [cross join](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join)).

Use modern join syntax specifying how the join should be made via the `ON` keyword, choosing a `LEFT` (ie *outer*) join so divisions without any employees are still returned (with count of 0):

```
SELECT
    division,
    COUNT (first_name) as employee_count
FROM departments d 
LEFT JOIN employees e ON e.department_id = d.id
GROUP BY division
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.division, COUNT (e.first_name) 
 FROM departments d 
 JOIN employees e on d.id=e.department_id
GROUP BY d.division
```

This construction FROM departments d, employees is a "cross-join" between two tables

Answer (score 0):

Where clause is missing,  put the relation between department and employee in the where clause